# Instantiate prefabs on endless runner top of previous one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing 2D Endless racer game, insted of constant background; i will use prefabs as background, i have 3 different prefabs as background: **(Please Check Image)**

- Straight Road
- Right Curved Road
- Left Curved Road

I want to instantiate endless prefabs, according to instantiate point of each prefab,
*I would appreciate for your support*

[**Goal Image and Prefabs**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qNLf.png)

Comment: This is not a request site, please at least attempt to solve the problem and show us your code.

Comment: Dear Aethers,
I am looking for an idea to code it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution come straight from the example image you posted. Each road piece has its own "exit point", symbolized by that yellow circle. Since each road piece is its own prefab, you could give each of them an empty child object, acting like your yellow circle.
Each object would then have a reference to that object, and would use that to spawn the next object.

```
public class RoadPiece : Monobehaviour
{
    public Transform nextInstantiatePoint;
```

To make the next road piece line up correctly, you could take advantage of the Sprite's Import Settings. Set the Pivot to "Bottom", or try the others for different effects.

[image]

The algorithm that you use to chose which piece to instantiate each time is up to you, but to start you could have an array of all the road pieces and pick one from there.
Ideally you want each object to wait some time before it instantiates the next, otherwise it will quickly cause the scene to be overcrowded. The easiest way to do it is like this:

```
    void Start()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(SpawnNext), waitTime);
    }

    void SpawnNext()
    {
        Instantiate(roadPiece, nextInstantiatePoint.position, nextInstantiatePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```